# JOIN with multiple COUNT columns

Tags: sql, join, count

```
course_modules
id course
1   3
2   3
3   6
4   8
5   8
23  9
46  9

user_completed_modules
id  coursemoduleid userid 
1        1           6
2        2           6
3        3           6
4        4           12
5        5           12
6        23          12
7      46          12

I need the output like

userid  course count(coursemoduleid) count(coursemodules)
 6       3               12               10
 6       8               8                10
 6       9               6                15
```

Here I need the `users completed modules` and the `count of modules in a course`
 I am extremely sorry for my english.

Can anyone help me with the query?

```
SELECT count(cm.id) AS "coursemodules",
(SELECT count(cmc.coursemoduleid) FROM user_completed_modules cmc 
JOIN course_modules cm ON cmc.coursemoduleid = cm.id 
WHERE cmc.userid = 6 AND cm.course = 8 ) AS "completedmodules"
ROM course_modules cm WHERE cm.course= 8
```

Comment: This depends the implementation. Without a useful PARTITION BY function, consider `SELECT .. FROM baseRelation LEFT JOIN derivedCount1 LEFT JOIN derviedCount2` (I also recommend avoiding [implicit] CROSS JOIN syntax.)

Comment: What database are you using?  And by what logic do your counts make sense?

Comment: I need to show an user completed modules in a course and total number of modules in a course

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT userid, cm.course, count(*), m.ct
     FROM user_completed_modules c JOIN
          course_modules cm ON cm.id = c.coursemoduleid JOIN
          (
            SELECT course, count(*) AS ct
               FROM course_modules GROUP BY course
          ) AS m ON cm.course = m.course
     GROUP BY userid, course, m.ct
```